# Removing URL .php extension gives 404 error

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, url

I am rewriting my url to get rid of the `.php` extension (and hopefully the get variables too as all the help I have gotten is great, but still wont work.

Here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now when I use this code, it takes the .php out, but then the error says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
```

Meanwhile, if I take that code out, it works fine, but has the `.php` extension

Comment: Well you hide the .php and you request it after. it won't find it without the extension. I'd suggest hiding the extension after.

Comment: @KRUKUSA if I do that, then it redirects me to my localhost core files (the MAMP localhost screen)

Comment: Im not great with this but what if you threw a statement in there like if / contains .php replace with .....

Comment: only you want to hide the extension ? OR you want to something more ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this code in **.htaccess** to remove **.php** extension and redirect **.php** extension pages to non **.php** extension pages :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(wp-admin)($|/) - [L] # You don't want to mess with WordPress 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule .* $0.php

 # browser requests PHP
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When the above code is used in **.htaccess**, you can access **PHP** pages without the extension and when a user visits a page with **.php** extension, he/she will be redirected to the page without the extension.

Example :

> http://example.com/page.php is redirected to http://example.com/page
>
> http://example.com/page will be the same as
>   http://example.com/page.php

There wouldn't be any problem when you access PHP files with extension internally :

```
<?
include("page.php");
?>
```

will work without any problem.

Comment: This works ! but I am having an issue, it is redirecting me to `localhost/mypage` where it needs to be `localhost/myproject/mypage`

Comment: And how can I take the GET variables out?

Comment: @user3241507 hmmm.. It's working well for me. Maybe there's another code in **.htaccess** that's conflicting with my code. I don't know any way to pass **GET** parameters with the redirect. You should change the .php URL's with `GET` parameters to non .php URLs with GET parameters

Comment: But how do I get it to access the subfolder and not the main site?

Comment: @user3241507 I updated the code on answer. Try it now. It may work

Comment: I am not using wordpress, this is a hand coded site. Not to sure how to change that to redirect to the `mysite` sub folder

Comment: @user3241507 Is there any other **.htaccess** files in your root directory or any other folders ? It may conflict with my .htaccess code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48185/discussion-between-subin-and-user3241507)

Comment: put this before wordpress RewriteRule for index.php, and it works

Comment: As i go with this solution, there something wrong with $_post parameter, all data gone redirected if i post request using /sample-thanks-page.php . `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]` , but when i remove it and request it like this : /sample-thanks-page ,the $_post data is appear. (i need to remove the redirection there, as i need to still accept those /*.php POST request ? )

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in `/myproject/.htaccess` (not in root):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myproject/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

And then test it from a new browser.