# cant load page without .php extension

Tags: php, url-rewriting

The pages load without any trouble when there is the **.php** extension with the URL but it gives error **Not Found** while trying to access the same page without **.php** extension.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**With extension**
[image]

---

**Without extension**
[image]

Before posting this I have searched a lot.

1. [mod_rewrite for removing .php extension is producing 404
   error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337282/mod-rewrite-for-removing-php-extension-is-producing-404-error)
2. [Using .htaccess for remove .php extension but folder access returns
   404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906596/using-htaccess-for-remove-php-extension-but-folder-access-returns-404)
3. [getting 404 error when removing file extension worked on wamp but
   not working on
   lamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768770/getting-404-error-when-removing-file-extension-worked-on-wamp-but-not-working-on)
4. [Removing URL .php extension gives 404
   error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964970/removing-url-php-extension-gives-404-error)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try and add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` as well.

Comment: Have to ask, are you using Apache?

Comment: yes ,apache2 ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Of course. The second screen shot even says so :-) Missed that. And you have mod_rewrite enabled? And you have restarted the apache server after it was installed?

Comment: ypz, mod_rewrite already enabled

Answer (score 0):

Just place the following into your .htaccess file (and make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

try to check your vhost the AllowOverride should be enabled.

Something like this :

```
<Directory /your/path/here>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: This is not a bad suggestion, but it is still a stab in the dark since we don't know if the OP already have this. Just a heads up: Suggestions like this (where we don't know enough) and questions should be written as comments, not as answers.